# change the area in a osm-request: from lon & lat to whole country

Tags: openstreetmap, php, apache, geotag

I am new to PHP's SimpleXML. the script below makes a starting point for my project. Below I have added my own answer to the question, how to refine the code to ad more tags.

I want to filter the data to get the nodes with special category. Here is sample of the OSM data I want to get the whole schools within an certain area.

The first script below runs well - but now I want to refine the search and add more tags. I want to store all into MySQL.So we need to make some XML parsing with PHP:

The following is a little OSM Overpass API example with PHP SimpleXML

NOTE: i want to change the values in the boundary-box. So that we can gather the shools from a certain area - eg. the country Italy

Q: is this possible?

see the script:

```
<?php
/**
 * OSM Overpass API with PHP SimpleXML / XPath
 *
 * PHP Version: 5.4 - Can be back-ported to 5.3 by using 5.3 Array-Syntax (not PHP 5.4's square brackets)
 */

//
// 1.) Query an OSM Overpass API Endpoint
//


$query = 'node
  ["addr:postcode"~"RM12"]
  (51.5557914,0.2118915,51.5673083,0.2369398);
  node
  (around:100000)
  ["amenity"~"school"];
           out;';

$context = stream_context_create(['http' => [
    'method'  => 'POST',
    'header' => ['Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'],
    'content' => 'data=' . urlencode($query),
]]);

# please do not stress this service, this example is for demonstration purposes only.
$endpoint = 'http://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter';
libxml_set_streams_context($context);
$start = microtime(true);

$result = simplexml_load_file($endpoint);
printf("Query returned %2\$d node(s) and took %1\$.5f seconds.\n\n", microtime(true) - $start, count($result->node));

//
// 2.) Work with the XML Result
//

# get all school nodes with xpath
$xpath = '//node[tag[@k = "amenity" and @v = "school"]]';
$schools = $result->xpath($xpath);
printf("%d School(s) found:\n", count($schools));
foreach ($schools as $index => $school)
{
    # Get the name of the school (if any), again with xpath
    list($name) = $school->xpath('tag[@k = "name"]/@v') + ['(unnamed)'];
    printf("#%02d: ID:%' -10s  [%s,%s]  %s\n", $index, $school['id'], $school['lat'], $school['lon'], $name);
}

?>
```

if we change this

```
$query = 'node
  ["addr:postcode"~"RM12"]
  (51.5557914,0.2118915,51.5673083,0.2369398);
  node
  (around:100000)
  ["amenity"~"school"];
           out;';

$context = stream_context_create(['http' => [
    'method'  => 'POST',
    'header' => ['Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'],
    'content' => 'data=' . urlencode($query),
]]);
```

we get more than 2170 results:

```
#2171: ID:2837001831  [51.1783749,-0.7970866]  More House School
#2172: ID:2865091022  [50.9090614,-0.5565425]  Dorset House School
#2173: ID:2882477853  [51.6261198,-0.7349665]  Bowerdean Primary School
#2174: ID:2901434856  [51.6542477,-0.3098923]  The Haberdashers' Aske's Girls School
#2175: ID:2901434857  [51.6565707,-0.3129822]  The Haberdashers' Aske's Boys School
```

NOTE: i want to change the values in the boundary-box. So that we can gather the shools from a certain area - eg. the country Italy or something thelike

is this possible?

**update:** can i do some rework of the area-data like so:

```
[place] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [place_id] => 331526
                    [osm_type] => node
                    [osm_id] => 96209423
                    [place_rank] => 15
                    [boundingbox] => 44.4361381530762,44.4361419677734,26.1027431488037,26.1027450561523
                    [lat] => 44.436139
                    [lon] => 26.1027436
                    [display_name] => BucureČti, Sector 2, Bucuresti, RomĂ˘nia, European Union
                    [class] => place
                    [type] => city
                    [importance] => 0.73231672860554
                    [icon] => http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/images/mapicons/poi_place_city.p.20.png
                )

        )
```

is this doable!`?

Comment: your need to download the data and use a database overpass api is for small extracts. http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/italy.html

Comment: How you want to get the coordinates of the country or the "certain area" either by importing boundary file or drawing over map or any other way?

Comment: hello you both - well i want to (if that is possible) do it with amenity:country. Is that possible? If not then i would like to work with coordinates of the country. Above all - i prefer to work with textual data; i try  to avoid working with the map itself. Hope i am able to make clear what is aimed!?

Comment: If you query the whole country, the overpass API might refuse your task. Using Geofabrik extracts you avoid that, working offline. Please note that some schools are included as nodes, while others are areas (polygons or multipolygons), or both.

Comment: thanks for the  hints. Guess that i will have more luck if workin with the downloaded files derived from geofabrik. The hints regarding the inclusion of schools in different way is just important - i need to get a way to gather them all.